# Pre-roll VAST on YouTube Video using Video.js

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, video.js, video-player

I try to make a pre-roll ads (VAST) on youtube video using video.js.
I have use plugin on github https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube , while for the ADs part I'm using this videojs-vast-plugin (https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin ).

When i use mp4 video format. the pre-roll ads work perfectly. But, if i use youtube video. The pre-roll ads not working.

How fix it? i want to use pre-roll ads (VAST) on youtube video with video.js?

this ismy code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Video.js VAST Example</title>
 <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="videojs.ads.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="videojs.vast.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .description {
      background-color:#eee;
      border: 1px solid #777;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: .8em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    .example-video-container {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="lib/es5.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
  <script src="videojs.ads.js"></script>
  <script src="vast-client.js"></script>
  <script src="videojs.vast.js"></script>
  <script src="youtube.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="description">Video.js VAST plugin with videojs-youtube.</p>

<div class="example-video-container">
<video id="video" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{ "width": "auto", "height": "auto", "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn-NsWRtaSY" }'>
  </video>

<script>
var vid = videojs("video");
vid.ads();
vid.vast({
      url: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x360&iu=/6062/iab_vast_samples/skippable&ciu_szs=300x250,728x90&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&correlator=[timestamp]'
    });
 
</script>

</div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is disabled since it would violate YouTube's TOS

See: https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/177

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

`<video id="Video_ID" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="metadata" >
<source  type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ">
</video>`

And for your Script:

```
videojs("Video_ID", { 

    nativeControlsForTouch: false, //This for mobile device touch
        plugins: {
                   //.... Your plugins
               ads:{}, //perhaps you will need this for ads init
               vast:{
                url: "http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=is&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=13569296&PluID=0&pos=1886&ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%&cim=1"
            } 
       },
       techOrder: ["Html5","youtube"] 
       },function(){
        //... Player (this) is initialized and ready.
    });
```